# System freezes when using i3 or bspwm

Tags: video, freeze, crash, i3-wm

When I am using standard Ubuntu load - everything is fine, I can work for hours.

I first tried installing i3 to replace standard Ubuntu, but it had that weird problem that when I used it for a couple of minutes - the system would freeze for a few seconds.

As I Linux-newbie I decided to switch wm instead of fixing the problem.

So today I installed bspwm with some additional stuff for a bar, terminal and wallpaper. I got everything working and… the same problem started happening When I log in with bspwm.

Looks like I can use terminal for long and nothing happens, but when I open vscode or Firefox - screen freezes in less than a minute. This time it doesn’t even unfreeze after some time so I just reboot.

Also something I noticed is that it looks like only *the screen* freezes, not the whole system. Because when the screen froze I could still play and pause a video that was playing on YouTube, but only knew that by the video sound, as the screen was frozen.

It's my first time seeking for help with my Linux, only thing i figured could hint you guys is this kernel file of a load that it froze last time:

[dmesg.0](https://github.com/kol3x/help/blob/main/documents)

Comment: MSI Gaming Laptop with dual GPU (Intel, Nvidia) and old Bios? That's a difficult combination for Linux, as the vendors use proprietary connection and do not support Linux. I guess the switch from Intel-GPU to Nvidia freezes the GUI.

Comment: @Marco wow that does make sense. Could I theoretically configure it so that the only Nvidia GPU works from the start ? And what do you recommend for future Linux setup? Amd? Should I try upgrading bios as well?

Comment: Bios update is always a risk, but I would do it. You must decide by yourself. For the "two GPUs" this might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46570/how-to-get-dual-graphic-cards-working-under-linux